# Including SQLite in release build Visual studio 2010

Tags: database, dll, sqlite, database-connection

I am currently developing a project for school.

We are told to include a database, and that this database should use the latest version of SQLite.

Inorder to use and edit the database we use 
sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3071700 from (http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

and we use this software to edit the design and input data in Visual studio 2010
sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-2010-1.0.83.0 
And it allows us to open a designer in Visual studio 2010 using the ADO.NET Entity Data Model

We are then including the references for 
System.Data.SQLite 
and
System.Data.SQLite.Linq
We also have a copy of the database including into the release folder.

Since it is not standard we make sure to copy them from local=true so that it is automaticly put into the Release folder for reference.

Now here comes the tricky part 
When we try to run the release exe on a pc with Visual studio 2010 or Visual studio 2012 without
sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-2010-1.0.83.0 
or newer installed then it won't work. 
But when we install this software onto the machine then it works.

But that is only if the end user machine has visual studio 2010 or 2012 installed.
If we try to install the two sqlite related pieces  from earlier 
sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-2010-1.0.83.0 
sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3071700
to the target machine(that does not have Visual studio 2010 or 2012 installed) 
Even then it will not work

So we are left with the issue that it simply crashes. 
And we are certain that it has to do with the database because when we remove the code that interact with the database, then it works fine on any end user machine we have tried it on so far.

Error Message:

Faulting application name: Project_66.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x51b1ab60
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18015, time stamp: 0x50b83c8a
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000c41f
Faulting process id: 0x1414
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce636a074b4367
Faulting application path: G:\Project66Release\Release\Project_66.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll

Application: Project_66.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException

```
Stack:
   at Project_66.DatabaseHandler.ImportBasicScenarios()
   at Project_66.Menu.ImportScenarios()
   at Project_66.Menu..ctor()
   at Project_66.Program.Main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need a statically-linked version of the SQLite .NET library, from http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki